# SQL not doing the join correctly

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a SQL statement with some JOIN condition it is working fine for all of them but not the last one the code is below:

```
SELECT 
    A.EMPL_CTG, 
    B.DESCR AS PrName, 
    SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) AS SALARY_COST_BUDGET, 
    SUM(A.BUDGET_AMT) AS BUDGET_AMT, 
    SUM(A.BUDGET_AMT)*100/SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) AS MERIT_GOAL,
    SUM(C.FACTOR_XSALARY) AS X_Programp, 
    SUM(A.FACTOR_XSALARY) AS X_Program,
    COUNT(A.EMPLID) AS EMPL_CNT, 
    COUNT(D.EMPLID),
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.PROMOTION_SECTION = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PRMCNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.EXCEPT_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXPCNT, 
    (SUM(CASE WHEN A.PROMOTION_SECTION = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN A.EXCEPT_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100/(COUNT(A.EMPLID)) AS PEpercent 
FROM 
    EMP_DTL A INNER JOIN EMPL_CTG_L1 B ON A.EMPL_CTG = B.EMPL_CTG  
    INNER JOIN 
    ECM_PRYR_VW C ON A.EMPLID=C.EMPLID 
    INNER JOIN ECM_INELIG  D on D.EMPL_CTG=A.EMPL_CTG and D.YEAR=YEAR(getdate()) 
WHERE 
    A.YEAR=YEAR(getdate()) 
    AND B.EFF_STATUS='A' 
GROUP BY 
    A.EMPL_CTG, 
    B.DESCR 
ORDER BY B.DESCR
```

The `COUNT(D.EMPLID)` is returning the same value as `COUNT(A.EMPLID)` but I need the count of `EMPLID`s for **Table D** in the join condition, any help?

Comment: could you share some sample data and explain what result you're trying to get?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) (and also the other [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)) doesn't process only the rows from one of the tables. They work on all the rows produced by the `JOIN`. The only difference between `COUNT(A.EMPLID)` and `COUNT(D.EMPLID)` is provided by the `NULL` values in the two columns. You should use `COUNT(DISTINCT D.EMPLID)` to get the value you need.

Comment: There is no error , the query is running well, but as a sample data lets say for EMPL_CNT it should be 42, and COUNT(D.EMPLID)=3 , but the query is returning:  EMPL_CNT=42 and COUNT(D.EMPLID)=42

Comment: axiac, yes you are right, thanks for the help, worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) (and also the other [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)) doesn't process only the rows from one of the tables.

They work on all the rows produced by the `JOIN`. If the `JOIN` without `GROUP BY` produces 42 rows then `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` returns `42` while `COUNT(A.EMPLID)` and `COUNT(D.EMPLID)` return the number of not-`NULL` values in those columns.

In order to get the number of rows extracted from one of the tables the you should use [`COUNT(DISTINCT)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct). It ignores the `NULL` values and also the duplicates produced by the `JOIN`.

Change `COUNT(D.EMPLID)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT D.EMPLID)`.