# SQL Condition for sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have a sql statement with many inner join tables, as you can see below I have many conditional SUM statements , these sums are giving me wrong (very large) numbers as the inner join is repeating the same values in my source select pool. I was wondering id there is a way to limit these sum conditions lets say to EMPLIDs. The code is :

```
SELECT 
    A.EMPL_CTG, 
    B.DESCR AS PrName, 
    SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) AS SALARY_COST_BUDGET, 
    SUM(A.BUDGET_AMT) AS BUDGET_AMT, 
    SUM(A.BUDGET_AMT)*100/SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) AS MERIT_GOAL,
    SUM(C.FACTOR_XSALARY) AS X_Programp, 
    SUM(A.FACTOR_XSALARY) AS X_Program,
    COUNT(A.EMPLID) AS EMPL_CNT, 
    COUNT(D.EMPLID),
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.PROMOTION_SECTION = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PRMCNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.EXCEPT_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXPCNT, 
    (SUM(CASE WHEN A.PROMOTION_SECTION = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN A.EXCEPT_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100/(COUNT(A.EMPLID)) AS PEpercent 
FROM 
    EMP_DTL A INNER JOIN EMPL_CTG_L1 B ON A.EMPL_CTG = B.EMPL_CTG  
    INNER JOIN 
    ECM_PRYR_VW C ON A.EMPLID=C.EMPLID 
    INNER JOIN ECM_INELIG  D on D.EMPL_CTG=A.EMPL_CTG and D.YEAR=YEAR(getdate()) 
WHERE 
    A.YEAR=YEAR(getdate()) 
    AND B.EFF_STATUS='A' 
GROUP BY 
    A.EMPL_CTG, 
    B.DESCR 
ORDER BY B.DESCR
```

I already tried moving D.YEAR=YEAR(getdate())  to the where clause. Any help would be greatly appereciated

Comment: mysql, or mssql? It can't be both...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL not doing the join correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805408/sql-not-doing-the-join-correctly)

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri it is not a possible duplicate , if you take a look on the other question you will see I already asked that one, and that one is refering to another problem. Here I wanna now how can I modify the SUM(CASE ...) lines

Comment: D.YEAR=YEAR(getdate()) set it on WHERE clause

Comment: @miglio I did try that as well, nothing changed in the results

Comment: Have you tried using `ROW_NUMBER` to partition by unique `EMPLID`? If you have multiple rows in the table your joining that have the same value in the source table, you're going to get a duplicate source record for every joined record.

Comment: @Prime03 It will pass an error to me, as my final query is already a group by EML_CTG which has a bunch of EMPID inside.

Comment: can you do the sum first and join later.

Comment: That's the best thing to do but, unfortunately due to server limitation no, I cant

Comment: i don't understand the server limitation part. I was suggesting you do it in sub queries and then join them. Not necessarily solve your problem, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason of your very large numbers is probably due to the result of Cartesian product of joining A -> B, A -> C and A -> D where tables C and D appear to have multiple records.  So, just example... if A has 10 records, and C has 10 for each of the A records, you now have 10 * 10 records...  Finally, join that to D table with 10 records, you now have 10 * 10 * 10 for each "A", thus your bloated answers.

Now, how to resolve.  I have taken your "C" and "D" tables and "Pre-Aggregated" those counts based on the join column basis.  This way, they will each have only 1 record with the total already computed at that level, joined back to A table and you lose your Cartesian issue.

Now, for table B, it appears that is a lookup table only and would only be a single record result anyhow.

```
SELECT 
      A.EMPL_CTG, 
      B.DESCR AS PrName, 
      SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) AS SALARY_COST_BUDGET, 
      SUM(A.BUDGET_AMT) AS BUDGET_AMT, 
      SUM(A.BUDGET_AMT)*100/SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) AS MERIT_GOAL,
      PreAggC.X_Programp, 
      SUM(A.FACTOR_XSALARY) AS X_Program,
      COUNT(A.EMPLID) AS EMPL_CNT, 
      PreAggD.DCount,
      SUM(CASE WHEN A.PROMOTION_SECTION = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PRMCNT,
      SUM(CASE WHEN A.EXCEPT_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXPCNT, 
      ( SUM( CASE WHEN A.PROMOTION_SECTION = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN A.EXCEPT_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) * 
           100 / COUNT(A.EMPLID) AS PEpercent 
   FROM 
      EMP_DTL A 
         INNER JOIN EMPL_CTG_L1 B 
            ON A.EMPL_CTG = B.EMPL_CTG  
           AND B.EFF_STATUS='A' 

         INNER JOIN ( select 
                            C.EMPLID,
                            SUM(C.FACTOR_XSALARY) AS X_Programp
                         from
                             ECM_PRYR_VW C
                         group by
                            C.EMPLID ) PreAggC
            ON A.EMPLID = PreAggC.EMPLID

         INNER JOIN ( select 
                            D.EMPLID,
                            COUNT(*) AS DCount
                         from
                             ECM_INELIG D 
                         where
                            D.Year = YEAR( getdate())
                         group by
                            D.EMPLID ) PreAggD
            ON A.EMPLID = PreAggD.EMPLID
   WHERE 
      A.YEAR=YEAR(getdate()) 
   GROUP BY 
      A.EMPL_CTG, 
      B.DESCR 
   ORDER BY 
      B.DESCR
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply DRapp, for sure it helped and it worked for some of them, but still is giving me wrong result for the comprate SUM(A.CURRENT_COMPRATE) although I had to change it to : SUM(CASE WHEN A.COMP_FREQUENCY='H' THEN A.CURRENT_COMPRATE*2080 ELSE A.CURRENT_COMPRATE END )

Comment: There is one more problem, having the two  PreAggC.X_Programp, and  PreAggD.DCount, will give me an error saying:  "Column 'PreAggD.DCount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." do you know how can I resolve it?

Comment: @user12321 Add `PreAggC.X_Programp, PreAggD.DCount` in your `GROUP BY` part ;).